# Regex get string in tag <p></p>

Tags: php, regex

I have this code:

```
$body = '<p>awesometext:data</p>';
preg_match_all("/<p>([^<]+)<\/p>/", $body, $matches);
$string = array_map('trim', $matches[1]);
```

In result I get empty array `$string`. How I can fix it?

String can be is more. Example:

```
$body = '<p>awesometext:data</p><p>othertext:data</p><p>sss:sddd</p>'; //e.t.c
```

Comment: Looks like it's working to me: https://eval.in/1073233

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Your examples have no leading/trailing whitespace. What do you want to happen? Do you have other examples?

Comment: Works fine for me too @RobbieAverill and also with the longer string

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, to get the strings inside the p tag you can:

```
let str = '<p>awesometext:data</p><p>othertext:data</p><p>sss:sddd</p>';
let matches = str.replace(/<p>|<\/p>/gi, ' ').trim().match(/([a-z]+?:[a-z]+)/gi);
```

`matches` would return an array of strings. Please note the above expression doesn't solve for edge cases. i.e leading/trail spaces, etc.

Comment: I need PHP, but not javascript